# AWS S3 - ListObjects returns incomplete directory listings

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I use `ListObject` function without any delimiters and as result I have something that look like:

```
/BF
/BF/FTP
/BF/MUSIC/LIBRARY/AUDITION/BEAKING%20EARLY.MP3
/BF/VIDEO/
/BF/VIDEO/Example
/BF/VIDEO/Example/test.mp4
```

The problem is in the music folder. Why ListObjects doesn't return S3Object with key: "/BF/MUSIC". There are many S3Objects with the same problem. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is S3 actually has a flat structure. There are no folders but it just recognizes the forward slashes so groups the ones having the same prefix under same folder. So in your example "/BF/MUSIC" would be just another object, not an empty folder.

> In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, where
>   objects are stored in buckets. Amazon S3 has a flat structure with no
>   hierarchy like you would see in a typical file system. However, for
>   the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports
>   the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this
>   by using key name prefixes for objects.

Source: [AWS Documentation: Working with Folders](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html)

Comment: I need to write something like folder explorer for bucket, do you have any idea how can I get path for example: "/BF/MUSIC" using ListObjects or something else ?

Comment: Not that I know of. You may need to come up with your own algorithm like treating everything before / as a subfolder and keeping track of them to group the objects.

Comment: @neustart47 that's what `delimiter` *is for*.  It returns "folders" in `<CommonPrefixes>` in the response XML.

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced a similar issue when tried to synchronize the folders and files from the S3 bucket using AWS SDK [ListObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) or [ListObjectV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property).

In my case, the reason is related to the files uploading process.
For example, when I'm creating a folder and uploading the file to that created folder, I'm able to receive both objects(folder and file).

```
/createdFolder
/createdFoder/example.pdf
```

But when I'm uploading the file using the AWS SDK [PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property), and training to upload the file to the directory which does not exist, using the key for example

```
/createdFoder/folder1/folder2/example.pdf
```

after the uploading, I can't see the following objects when training to get objects list

```
/createdFoder/folder1
/createdFoder/folder1/folder2
```

It returns only `/createdFoder/folder1/folder2/example.pdf`.

As a solution in my case, I have added the validation and checking if the folders exist using [HeadObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property). If it returns 404 status, it means the folder does not exist.

> IMPORTANT: If you are using HeadObject the `/` at last of Key parameter is required. For example, the key will look like `/createdFoder/folder1/`.

And I have also added the ability to add a folder. Using the same PutObject but without providing the buffer, and using the Key something like

```
/createdFolder/newFolder/
```

When the folder was created with the way provided above, the ListObjects is returning the object as a separate object.