# All folder names are not coming in List objects call of Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Di0.png)I'm using the following code to list all the objects present in the bucket of S3. But the problem is not all the folder names are coming in the call. I've attached the image for reference.

```
AmazonS3 s3Object = AmazonS3Utils.getS3Object(amazonS3ConnectionValues.regionName, amazonS3ConnectionValues.accessKey, amazonS3ConnectionValues.secretKey);
                s3Object.listBuckets();
                ListObjectsV2Result objectsList = s3Object.listObjectsV2(bucket);
                List<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummaries = objectsList.getObjectSummaries();
                for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectSummaries) {
                    Object[] newRow;
                    newRow = RowDataUtil.allocateRowData(data.outputRowMeta.size());
                    int index = 0;
                    newRow[index++] = objectSummary.getKey();
                    newRow[index++] = objectSummary.getETag();
                    newRow[index++] = objectSummary.getSize();
                    newRow[index++] = objectSummary.getLastModified();
                    newRow[index++] = objectSummary.getStorageClass();
                    putRow(data.outputRowMeta, newRow);
```

As shown in the image foldername **"automationedge123/"** is not shown in the response, other folder names such as **"Test Folder/", "automationedge/"** are shown in the output. I'm not understanding this behavior.

Comment: There is no image atttached.

Comment: Hello Marcin, I've uploaded the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listObjects result might be paginated. Make sure that you are not looking at a truncated result by looking at the return value of `isTruncated()` ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Result.html#isTruncated--)).

Here's a quote from the javadoc of `listObjects(...)]` ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects-java.lang.String-))

> Because buckets can contain a virtually unlimited number of keys, the
> complete results of a list query can be extremely large. To manage
> large result sets, Amazon S3 uses pagination to split them into
> multiple responses. Always check the ObjectListing.isTruncated()
> method to see if the returned listing is complete or if additional
> calls are needed to get more results. Alternatively, use the
> AmazonS3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(ObjectListing) method as an easy
> way to get the next page of object listings.

Comment: I tried using the above way, but the response is still the same as given in the query.

Comment: what is the result of `isTruncated()`?

Comment: isTruncated() method is false. And the result is the same as that of the query.

Comment: looking closely at your image again, is it possible that you are running into this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565321/aws-s3-listobjects-returns-incomplete-directory-listings

Comment: Went through the StackOverflow link you provided, my case is the same as that of mentioned in the above problem.